# Google Developer - API Key Expires Every 24 Hours

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine

I have the following setup on my Google Developer Console. The problem is that my "Key for server applications" keeps on expiring every 12-24 hours. The "Key for Android applications", and "Key for iOS applications" never expire however. This is obviously frustrating as my apps stop working everyday and I can't have that happen in production. I have a credit card on file so I'm sure it doesn't have to do with a limited/trial account; unless I'm missing something.

Any help is much appreciated.
Zee

### OAuth

- Client ID for Android application
- Client ID for iOS application

### Public API access

- Key for server applications

  - **Status:** Active until May 21, 2015, 5:55:00 PM
- Key for Android applications
- Key for iOS applications

Attached is the screenshot of the Google Developer Console. This is what it looks like every 24 hours when it it no longer active. I can provide a screenshot of what I see when I regenerate the key if needed.

[image]

Comment: how you know it expired? (show exact error)

Comment: @ZigMandel I know because the status on the Google Developer Console says inactive and the functionality in the apps stop working. When I regenerate the key, and update them on the server, everything works again. Hope that answers the question.

Comment: havent seen that but will help others who answer

Comment: AFAIK Server keys have no expiration date. Where exaclty are you getting that they are expired?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the Developers Console if that's where you're seeing this? Or, how are you generating these keys? I feel you should provide us with some links to documentation related to what you're doing, etc.

Comment: @Nick I've attached a screenshot. This is what it looks like every 24 hours when it it no longer active. I can provide a screenshot of what I see when I regenerate the key if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen if you click "Regenerate key" on a normal key, which, when created, should exist forever. If you do this once, though, it enters the state where it needs to be updated every 24 hours.

You can create a new key if you did this by accident, and if you don't click "Regenerate key", it should never expire.

I figured this out by generating a new key which had no expiry, [reading the docs](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#apikeybestpractices), and clicking the "Regenerate key" button, which made the expiry date appear.